# If $p_n$ is prime does $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} $ or $\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}$ tend towards some number for large $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p_n$ is the nth prime  number does $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}$ approach any particular number when $n$ is large? What about $\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}$? Is it possible to prove that the limits converge or diverge with elementary methods?

Comment: $p_n \sim n\ln n$ by PNT, hence $1$ for both questions.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Interesting, thank you.

Comment: @mfl I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: Although I don't know if the prime number theorem falls under "elementary methods".